# Eclipse RCP - JAXB exception in program but not in minimal example: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement nor any of its super class is known to this context

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, jaxb, eclipse-rcp, marshalling

I am getting a weird bug which happens when my code is executed through my program but not when I run it in a standalone main method.

The code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JAXBContext jaxbContext =
            JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
    Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    JAXBElement<MyTestObject> marshallableSchedule =
            new ObjectFactory()
                    .createMyTestObject(new MyTestObject());
    marshaller.marshal(marshallableSchedule, System.out);
}
```

The code is exactly the same in my program but yet I get the following exception when it is invoked:

`javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement nor any of its super class is known to this context.`

I also noticed that if I do `jaxBContext.toString()` then the working example will show all of the classes from the package which `ObjectFactory` is inside, whereas the failing example only shows package.ObjectFactory.

I found a lot of duplicate questions like this one but it usually said MyTestObject is not known, not JAXBElement is not known.

Is this something to do with the way my projects are setup? I am using eclipse RCP with features and plugins if that makes any difference. I have considered this could be a classloader issue but I'm still not sure if it is or how to fix it.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Eclipse uses an elaborate system of class loaders to keep plugin class paths separate. This may be upsetting JAXB - I don't know enough about that to say.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Java for both tests? That is, does your eclipse-rcp plugin require a higher or lower Java version than you're using for your main() test?

Answer (score 0):

What is the class of the object created by `ObjectFactory().createMyTestObject(new MyTestObject())`? `ObjectFactory` ?
Statement `JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class)` tells JAXB to consider only instances of this class..
I have the feeeling that it should be `JAXBContext.newInstance(MyTestObject.class)` ...
Also the `AXBElement<MyTestObject>` construction is only required if class `MyTestObject` is not valid for JAXB (Add an `@XmlRootElement annotation if you can)
The code could be

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(MyTestObject.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
MyTestObject marshallableSchedule = new MyTestObject();
marshaller.marshal(marshallableSchedule, System.out);
```